# .NET Core - File paths from Path.Combine do not work in Docker

Tags: docker, .net-core

I’m trying to get my application running in a Docker container. Now I have a problem with file paths that are generated by dotnet core.

I changed my file paths according to this entry: [Cross-platform file name handling in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168391/cross-platform-file-name-handling-in-net-core?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

The output from dotnet core is the following for the path: **/app/\foo/bar.txt** *(This throws a ‘Could not find part of the path’ exeption.)*

If I hard code the path like this, it works: **/app/foo/bar.txt**

What can I change to get it working on Linux and Windows?

Comment: How do you generate your paths? I never hit this problem.
I

Comment: For example like this: System.IO.Path.Combine(PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath.TrimEnd('\\')), @"\foo\", @"bar.txt");
This outputs ' /app/\foo/bar.txt'

Comment: Can you just drop the "\" characters around foo, they cause the problems.
If you cannot do this, there is Path.FullPath Method which should normalize all chars

Comment: But for example what happens if  @"\foo\" would look like this  @"\foo\too\moo\"? I can't just drop the "\" characters in this case. I will try the Path.FullPath Method.

Comment: Hi, have you resolved the issue somehow?

Comment: @MG I fixed it with the following code "filePath.Replace('\\', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);"

Comment: /app/foo/bar.txt should work on both windows and linux. It works for me.