# Cross-platform path to save web API data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1, entity-framework-core-2.1

Does ASP.NET Core 2.1 offer a cross-platform way to specify a path where to save application data?

The closest solution I've found is to store data in either

- `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` or
- `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`

Yet, I'm not sure that matches standard practices.

Does anyone know if there is a cross-platform way to specify the data folder to be used by a web API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-platform file name handling in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168391/cross-platform-file-name-handling-in-net-core)

Comment: @p3tch this question isn't exactly a duplicate of that question as it is a generic question on how to handle file names in a cross-platform manner while my question is about determining the right path to save Web app data in a cross-platform manner.