# Define the directory separator used by System.IO.Path

Tags: c#

I'm writing a programm that runs on a Linux machine and needs to connect to a Windows SMB share.

Using `Path.Join(path1, path2)` it will use the forward slash `/` as directory separator. However the SMB share is on Windows and needs the backslash `\` as separator.

Is there some easy inbuilt way to concatenate paths using a defined directory separator without just calling `.Replace('/', '\\')` on the result?

Comment: Windows supports using either the backslash OR the forward slash as separators, so can't you just use `/` ? That's even [recommended by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar?view=net-6.0).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168391/cross-platform-file-name-handling-in-net-core

Comment: The only real solution to my problem in the linked questions is using `.Replace('/', '\\')`. I was hoping for something built into the framework so I can tell it in advance what kind of seperators I want without it using the separator of the OS my application is running on.

Comment: @wertzui Please show the source code you use to access/use the SMB share. The `System.IO.Path` class is used for file system related path operations, not for URLs.

Comment: @Progman I'm using the https://github.com/ume05rw/EzSmb which passes the path to https://github.com/TalAloni/SMBLibrary which writes the path as UTF8-bytes in the buffer field specified by the SMB2 protocol here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-smb2/e8fb45c1-a03d-44ca-b7ae-47385cfd7997. So, no transformation is going on, it is basically going straight into the underlying Socket and to the SMB (Windows) Server.